# Отправка уведомления о запуске бота юзерам. Telegram Aiogram Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Пытаюсь отправить каждому id в бд уведомление о запуске.
Появляется ошибка `on_startup() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import CommandStart
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage


con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str):
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_id, user_name,user_surname, username))
  con.commit()

async def on_startup():
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM test')
    arr = []
    arr = cursor.fetchall()
    for user_id in arr:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Бот запущен!")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True, on_startup = on_startup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# замени
async def on_startup():
# на
async def on_startup(dispatcher):
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KBkLsT0

Comment: Ну так, это же уже совсем другая ошибка. Тебе так и говорит, что такого чата не существует. Принтани что у тебя на каждой итерации в user_id

Comment: https://ibb.co/LdkmMgj

Comment: я так понимаю в запятых проблема?

Comment: потому что с cursor.fetchone()
всё работает, приходит на 1 аккаунт

Comment: Ну так ты же получаешь кортежи обратись по нулевому элементу и все user_id[0]